# Media queries working on desktop when resizing the browser but not on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have put in my meta tag in the head of the document however when I load the website on my iphone or ipad, it still looks the same as the desktop site.
You can view my website which is live at www.thairapyexeter.co.uk

My HTML:

```
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Thairapy Hair, Beauty + Barbers</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
```

Heres an example of how I have written my media queries:

CSS:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
/* Styles */
.menu nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%!important;
  position: relative;
  height: 33%!important;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.offersmenu nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lightbox-prev, .lightbox-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 60px;
    background: center no-repeat red;
    z-index: 1001;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1004;
}
.treatmentsmenu nav ul li {
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
}
.lightbox-prev {
    background-image: url("../previous.png")!important;
}
.lightbox-next {
    right: 0;
    background-image: url("../next.png")!important;
}
```

Comment: instead media only screen -  media screen

Comment: It's missing a `}` for close the media query.

Answer (score -1):

Check this code between your code

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  /* please write one time in head section */
</head>
```

CSS media query:

```
/* small device code here */
@media (min-width: 480px){
  /* media code here */
  /* Mobile */
}    
@media (min-width: 750px){
  /* media code here */
  /* Mobile or tab */
}
@media (min-width: 960px){
  /* media code here */
  /* desktop or Ipad */
}    
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  /* media code here */
  /* desaktop */
}
@media (min-width: 1600px){
  /* media code here */
  /* desktop */
}    
@media (min-width: 1920px){
  /* media code here */
  /* desktop */
}
```